# Unable to register a plain function through clientScript->registerScript in yii

Tags: yii

I'm calling a simple javascript function via `onchange`

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'job_title', $jobTypes, array('onchange'=>'jobTitle(this);')); ?>
```

Trying to register `jobTitle` via `clientScript->registerScript`

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('jobTitle', "
    function jobTitle(e) {
        alert('e');
    }
");
```

Yet I'm getting an error that `jobTitle` is not defined...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The Reason:**

As the [default position](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#defaultScriptPosition-detail) is `CClientScript::POS_READY`, the generated js is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // ... there could be some other yii scriptlets too ...
    function jobTitle(e) {
        alert('e');
    }
});
```

Which means your function `jobTitle` is available only within the `jQuery();` function scope and not from outside it, and that's why you get the undefined error.

**Solution 1:**

If you use the positions : `CClientScript::POS_HEAD` or `CClientScript::POS_BEGIN` or `CClientScript::POS_END` with your `registerScript` call, i.e:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('jobTitle', "
    function jobTitle(e) {
        alert('e');
    }
", CClientScript::POS_END);
```

the function will be defined outside, and in the global scope, and then you will be able to use the function.

**Solution 2:**

Alternatively if you need the function within [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), i.e within `jQuery(function($){});`, you can define the function in the global window object, and still access it from outside:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('jobTitle', "
    window.jobTitle = function jobTitle(e) {
        alert('e');
    }
");
```

**Solution 3:**

Or you can simply add an event handler from jQuery itself, instead of doing it inline in the html:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('jobTitle', "
    $('body').on('change', 'id-of-job-title-input', function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
");
```